# How can I replace this code with one if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, puzzle

For the sake of challenge, how can I replace this code with only one if statement?

```
unsigned int x, y;
cin>>x;
if((x>=0)&&(x<=1)) y = 1;
else if (x<=3) y = 2;
    else if(x<=5) y = 3;
        else y = 6;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get it to one `if` statement? Readability? Performance? Challenge?

Comment: There is not a clean way to do that.  Maybe a better question is: why do you *want* to replace that code with a single `if`?

Comment: Challange, maybe I can replace all of that with the Conditional operator ‘?’, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: `int y = (0 <= x && x <= 5) ? x / 2 + 1: 6;`?

Comment: `0 <= x` for `unsigned int` is always `true` BTW.

Comment: `y = 6; if (x <= 5) y = (x/2 + 1);` will do it.

Comment: `if (true) y = 1 + (x >= 2) + (x >= 4) + 3*(x >= 6);`

Comment: @Alexander next time consider posting code challenges on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ instead ;)

Comment: @JanHohenheim from the `puzzle` tag description: "DO NOT USE - prefer constructive questions, or use more descriptive tags"

Comment: ...Otherwise, your question might be appropriate for CodeGolf.

Comment: look mum, no divs ;)
```static int value[6]={1,1,2,2,3,3};  y=(x<=5) ? value[x] : 6;```

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yep, hence my last comment to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing why you want to use a single `if`, it's hard to tell. Of course, you can use ternary operators without any `if`s:

```
unsigned int x, y;
cin>>x;
y = x<=1
? 1
: x<=3 
    ? 2
    : x<=5
      ? 3
      : 6;
```

Or ugly boolean casting hacks for exactly one `if` (please don't actually do this outside of a puzzle or codegolf context):

```
unsigned int x, y;
cin>>x;
if (x<=5) {
    y = 1 + (int)(x == 2 || x == 3) + (int)(x == 4 || x == 5);
} else {
    y = 6;
}
```

Or, if you insist on *exactly* one `if`:

```
unsigned int x, y;
cin>>x;
if (x <= 5) {
   y = x/2 + 1;
} else {
   y = 6;
}
```

@Pietrek's answer shows you the better variant with a ternary operator (slightly modified here):

```
unsigned int x, y;
cin>>x;
auto const cutoff = 6;
y = x < cutoff ? x/2 + 1 : cutoff;
```

Note that in any case `x >= 0` is always true when working with `unsigned` data types, so I omitted it.

---

If this is not purely a puzzle challenge but actual production code, please use the last example and make the number `6` a `const` or `constexpr` with a meaningful name.

Comment: The version with `min` doesn't work for x = 6

Comment: @anatolyg good catch! Gonna fix it

Answer (score 2):

Make a table of inputs and outputs:

```
0 — 1
1 — 1
2 — 2
3 — 2
4 — 3
5 — 3
Other — 6
```

Now make a logical expression which distinguishes specific inputs from "others".

```
x ≥ 0 and x ≤ 5
```

(note: for `unsigned` type you can remove the comparison with 0)

Now make a formula which calculates given outputs from given inputs:

```
x / 2 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
y = x <= 5 ? x / 2 + 1 : 6;
```